# using ajax: hide div, replacewith, reattach behavior then show

Tags: jquery

**UPDATE**: HERE'S A JSFIDDLE SHOWING THE PROBLEM

http://jsfiddle.net/JPqhz/1/

I'm trying to do something similar to github's file browser.

https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask

(Just click a folder to demo. The only difference is what I want is a right 'slide' for the show.)

I have an ajax call which returns some json and that is used to replace a div.  I have it mostly working but I can't figure out that jquery that I would use for the following:

1. hide() the existing div that I want to replace with a jqueryUI 'slide' effect
2. replace the content using replaceWith (for various reasons I cannot use html() it needs to be replaceWith() but keep it hidden
3. Reattach some jquery behaviors to the new content (this code is Drupal specific, but it's a one-liner.  It reattaches other jquery behaviors to the new content) and the content is still hidden.
4. show() the new div with a jqueryUI 'slide' effect

I've tried many different things.  I know ajax is asynchronous so I need to run this in callbacks or chain the behaviors.  So far I'm up to this:

```
/* this snippet occurs in an $.ajax success: function, argumentWrapper is the div
wrapper to replace, newContent is the new html that will be inserted */

argumentWrapper.hide({
    effect: 'slide',
    direction: 'left',
    complete: function() {
         argumentWrapper.replaceWith(function() {
              return $(newContent).hide({
                   complete: function(){
                        Drupal.attachBehaviors(newContent);
                   }
              }).show({
                   effect: 'slide',
                   direction: 'right'
              });
         });
    }
});
```

This almost works, but before it slides back in I get a strange 'bunching-up' effect.  Like a pause with a very then div on the left side.

**UPDATE**: HERE'S A JSFIDDLE SHOWING THE PROBLEM

http://jsfiddle.net/JPqhz/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution if you use a container to wrap the content.  (Credit to chinoto in freenode #jquery):

http://jsfiddle.net/JPqhz/7/

```
   var
    $container=$('#container')
    ,wrapper = $("#wrapper")
    ,newContent = '<div id="dynamic">This is new information<div class="clickme"></div></div>';


$container.on('click','.clickme',function(event) {
    $container.hide({
        effect: 'slide',
        direction: 'left',
        complete: function () {
            (function() { //put me in post function
                wrapper.html(newContent);
                //Drupal reattach behaviors goes here
                $container.show({
                    effect: 'slide',
                    direction: 'right'
                });
            })()
        }
    });

});
```